# ConTeXt: Mix XHTML and TeX commands

Tags: math-mode, context, xml, xhtml

## Background

A document, having inline math statements, is being written in Markdown. The document is converted to XHTML for subsequent processing using ConTeXt.

## Problem

The XHTML contains XML elements with inline TeX commands. The inline TeX commands are not interpreted by ConTeXt, resulting in output similar to the following:

[image: Output document]

## SSCCE

Consider the following buffered XHTML snippet (e.g., generated from Markdown):

```tex
\startbuffer[document]
<body>
<p>$N = R_{*} \cdot f_{p} \cdot n_{e} \cdot f_{l} \cdot f_{i} \cdot f_{c} \cdot L$</p>
</body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body|p}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body \xmlflush{#1} \stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \xmlflush{#1}\par
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{xhtml}{document}{}
\stoptext
```

## Idea 1 - Syntax

It's possible to produce documents that export new XHTML elements, such as:

```xml
<tex>$N = R_{*} \cdot f_{p} \cdot n_{e} \cdot f_{l} \cdot f_{i} \cdot f_{c} \cdot L$</tex>
```

Or even without the `$` sigil:

```xml
<tex>N = R_{*} \cdot f_{p} \cdot n_{e} \cdot f_{l} \cdot f_{i} \cdot f_{c} \cdot L</tex>
```

However, TeX allows for both inline `$` and block-level `$$` syntax. These could be exported as `tex_inline` and `tex_block` elements, respectively, but that seems like duplication because ConTeXt already contains the parsing logic.

## Idea 2 - Setups

The problem is likely with the setups. Variations, such as those from the [steps document](https://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/context/latest/doc/context/documents/general/manuals/steps-mkiv.pdf), did not result in typeset math:

```tex
\startbuffer[document]
<body>
<tex>$N = R_{*} \cdot f_{p} \cdot n_{e} \cdot f_{l} \cdot f_{i} \cdot f_{c} \cdot L$</tex>
</body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body|p|tex}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

% ...

\startxmlsetups xml:tex
  \mathematics{\xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups
```

Even if it worked, this approach may prove problematic because users can insert (inline) TeX into any element: p, blockquotes, emphasis, strong, td, li, etc.

## Idea 3 - Convert to MathML

[itex2MML](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/%7Edistler/blog/itex2MML.html) and [TeX4ht](https://tug.org/tex4ht/) both convert TeX to MathML, but such a step should not be needed.

## Question

How would you embed inline/block-level TeX macros anywhere inside a well-formed XHTML document such that the macros will be typeset by ConTeXt?

(MathML is not a viable option for writing inside Markdown; conversion afterwards may be feasible.)

## References

- [Dealing with XML in ConTeXt MKIV](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xml-mkiv.pdf)
- [XML in ConTeXt](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/example.pdf)
- [Generating web and PDF output from once source](https://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/tas/xhtml.pdf)
- [Mixing XML and ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mixing_XML_and_ConTeXt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```tex
% ...
  <tex>$N = R_{*} \cdot f_{p} \cdot n_{e} \cdot f_{l} \cdot f_{i} \cdot f_{c} \cdot L$</tex>  
% ...

\startxmlsetups xml:tex
  \xmlflushcontext{#1}
\stopxmlsetups
```

Using `$$` also works.

Comment: It works if you remove `\startimath` and `\stopimath`, which are ConTeXt equivalents of inline math mode (`$ ... $`). Nice allusion to alien life, btw.

Comment: I worked with your first example: using ```\startxmlsetups xml:p
\xmlflushcontext{#1}
\par
\stopxmlsetups
``` gives the expected result. I'm on ConTeXt 2021.03.20 01:07

Comment: Using `xml:p` and `xmlflushcontext` errors out because XHTML documents can contain `<p><img .../></p>`. A `<tex>` tag that isolates `\xmlflushcontext` from otherwise un-flushable HTML elements seems necessary.